# How can I configure Password Policy(Group Policy) using c#

Tags: c#, windows, group-policy, windows-security, password-policy

How can I configure Password policy in windows using group policy in c#.
I need to set local GPO in device using C#.
computer configuration >> windows settings >> security settings >> account policies >> Password policy
I need to read this and set new password policy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, let me just say you are trying to tackle a very difficult task. The way I would try to tackle this would be to try find and modify the **registry keys** pertaining to those policies but that by itself is not an easy feat, you can see for yourself if you monitor the registry activity using something like **ProcMon** (Process Monitor). It might end up being more work than it is worth.

But say you do have a scriptable solution that you can run through command line for a batch file, then the way I would go about it in C# is create a new `Process` and run shell commands that way or create a batch file and execute from the code. Check this post for more info: [Run Command Prompt Commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469764/run-command-prompt-commands)

Or another way is to directly modify the registry keys in your code using the `Registry` and `RegistryKey` class from the **Microsoft.Win32** namespace. Check out this example: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/f9f215/windows-registry/

Unless there is an specific reason, if your doing this so that you don't have to change it manually every time then I would recommend just creating security template, an **INF** file and then importing it. Just do **Win + R** and type in `secpol.msc` and right click on `Security Settings` and there will be an **import/export** option. In the end, it might work to your advantage to use a security template in terms of saving time or just doing it manually through `secpol.msc`. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the help i will create a template and import it @Samuel Park